# Prevent multiple login of same account (Desktop app)

Tags: authentication, session, jwt, desktop-application

I have a **Desktop Application** developed with python and pyqt5.
I want to implement a login system for some reasons.

### the scenario will be like this (this section is done so far):

1. Client has created an account on my website and downloaded my desktop application.
2. They run the application for the first time => A login window displayed asking users to input their data.
3. The application made a request to URL: http://ip/api/login with a JSON object {username, plaim_pw} (the API developed with Flask).
4. The API will process that request and check whether that user's data inside that request exist or not and if that PW is correct or not then it will return a response.
5. If the user successfully logged in then every run time the app will not ask the user again about his/her data, it will be stored somewhere in their machine.

### What I want is:

- If user **' A'** successfully Logged in with account **' X'**, And at the same time user **'B'** trying to log in with the same account that user **' A'** is using => Then I want to tell user **'B'**: *"can't log-in at the time because another user using the same account"* or something like that. **in short description**: only one user can use the same account at the same time.

### My questions are:

1. How to accomplish that mechanism? is it good or bad?
2. I read about **JWT**, could it be helpful in my case? If so, Then how should I implemented it?

### Here is extra information:

- I don't have many APIs, I only have a route for "login" nothing more for now, And I want the login system for some reason.
- And in the future, I will be using **HTTPS** instead of **HTTP**.

Answer (score 0):

Once the user has logged in write this down on the server. Then the subsequent login attempt can check this. When checking consider an expiration timestamp. This can easily solve the first question. Consider looking at topics such as session management: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_(computer_science), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_ID.

JWT is not necessary for your scenario yet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Could you please tell me why JWT is not necessary? What if I added some API (other routs)?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The JWT token is used to securely transmit information between parties and contains all the required information about an entity to avoid querying a database more than once. The recipient of a JWT also does not need to call a server to validate the token. Based on the description you're not sending claims what the user can do, only limiting the parallel sessions, so you don't need it. More details here https://auth0.com/docs/security/tokens/json-web-tokens. If you add more endpoints (APIs) you'd take the logged in user from the session.